# Icon on Android Closing Screen

Tags: android, flutter

I'm working in Flutter and am using Visual Studio Code.  I am done with my app and am just testing it on a bunch of different devices to make sure that it works correctly.  I've noticed that when I close the app, there's an icon that appears at the top:

[image]

I've created icons for my app and it looks correct in the app tray.

[image]

What needs to be changed so that my icon displays when closing the app?  I have another app that is working correctly, but I cannot figure out the difference.

Answer (score 0):

You should generate app icons using android-studio's built-in [Image Asset Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/image-asset-studio),
Image Asset Studio will automatically generate all the necessary icons for you.
o start Image Asset Studio, follow these steps:

To start Image Asset Studio, follow these steps:

1. In the Project window, select the Android view.
2. Right-click the **res** folder and select **New** > **Image Asset**.
3. Select Icon-Type as **Launcher icons (adaptive and legacy)**
4. In foreground layer tab, choose your icon file
5. Click on **Next** and then **Finish.**

Comment: I am using Visual Studio Code and not Android Studio.

Comment: This worked for me, though I did have to delete the app and restart the phone for it to take effect.